# Not able to change <title> tag without error heroku

Tags: html, css, node.js, web, heroku

OK this might be user error but whenever I try to change the title tag on my Heroku website I get an application error. I followed the tutorial on the Heroku website to make a node.js website that commits to GitHub which then serves to heroku. All I did was change the title tag in the header.ejs file and now when I open my page I get an application error. Here's what the output is in my console when I push to Heroku

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 482 bytes | 482.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  12.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.4
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:
remote:        > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_c695ccb72d0772c3b509ad9fd8557d1d/node_modules/ejs
remote:        > node ./postinstall.js
remote:
remote:        added 145 packages in 3.217s
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 84 packages and audited 139 packages in 1.734s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 23.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v22
remote:        https://flamegames.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/flamegames.git
   302eafd..030aebf  master -> master
```

Comment: what is the error from heroku logs tail ?

Comment: if you didn't change the title, does it still deploy successfully?

Comment: I fixed it. The error had nothing to do with the title tag I didn't import some npm modules properly